# Qt session management on Android and IOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, session

I am currently developing an app for Android and IOS using Qt Quick Controls 2 which will have login possibility. The account credentials will be stored into an external SQL database. I have figured out how I can interact with the database, but I am not able to figure out how I can use sessions in Qt for Android and IOS such that the user do not need to type the login credentials each time.

One possible way could be to store the credentials to a file locally on the phone, and then access the file each time the app is started. However, I am not sure if this is the best and safest way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QSettings** class is used for state management. QSettings information is often stored in the system registry on Windows, and in property list files on macOS and iOS. Here is raw example code that uses QSettings to store/retrieve session parameters .. you can extend to include needed session login management scenarios:

main.cpp

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
QApplication app( argc, argv );
app.setOrganizationName("myOrg");
app.setOrganizationDomain("myOrg.net");
app.setApplicationName("qsettings-test");
MyMainWindow mw;
mw.show();
return app.exec();
}
```

Then in your source .cpp

```
void MyMainWindow::readSettings() {
QSettings settings;
QString user = settings.value("UserName");
int lifTime = settings.value("sessionLifeTime").toInt();;
QByteArray state = settings.value("state", QByteArray())
                                               .toByteArray();
restoreState(state);
}

// ...... lots of your code 

void MyMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event) {
if (maybeSave()) {
    writeSettings();
    event->accept();
} else {
    event->ignore();
}
}


void MyMainWindow::writeSettings() {
    /* Save postion/size of main window */
    QSettings settings;
    settings.setValue("sessionLifeTime", 7);
    settings.setValue("UserName", user);
    settings.setValue("state", saveState());
}
```

You can also access INI and PLIST configuration files with **QSettings** class, For Android this can be considered where your INI file must be copied during build (store in res folder and include it in .pro ).